# how to prevent uiwebview from access server

Tags: ios, webview

I call loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL: to load content into a webview.
in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType I have to return Yes, otherwise webview won't diaplay the content.
but I already have the data, so i don't need webview to really access baseURL.
what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason. I have an  with blank src.

Answer (score 0):

It won't access the baseURL. That parameter is there for relative URLs inside the web page you are supplying. If there are no relative URLs the baseURL can even be nil. However, if there *are* relative URLs (e.g. `<img>` tags) then of course the web view must get them from somewhere else.

Comment: but it does access the baseurl. I am sure that there are no relative paths inside the html file. and it accesses nothing but only the baseurl, maybe because all the resources(images, js, etc.) are bundled with the application.

Comment: for some pages it accesses the baseurl, for some pages it doesn't.i'm still looking for the difference. the baseurl i am using is like http://xxx.com/yyy/zzz/. if there are relative URLs like http://xxx.com/yyy/zzz/www/, it should access /www/ instead. why it only accesses http://xxx.com/yyy/zzz/.

Comment: You have it backwards `xxx.com/yyy/zzz/www` is not a relative URL, so the web view must access it. `www` is a relative (partial) URL, and in that case the web view will construct `xxx.com/yyy/zzz/www` (and will access it).